# Counting rel number from html selectbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Probably the most simple question, but it has kept me busy for hours. 
Lately, I am trying to study more jquery.

I have made two select boxes with `rel` attributes. 
In here you can find a number.

For example

```
<input type="checkbox" rel="600">
<input type="checkbox" rel="1200">
```

Now when these both are selected I want to count the `rel` numbers up. 
The total needs to be 1800.

I have tried many things, but it really doesn't seem to work.

```
var modules = 0;
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    modules += $(this).attr('rel'); 
});

alert(modules);
```

This above is getting me as closed, but it keeps saying 600,1200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the return `rel` value to an integer to perform arithmetic operations:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    modules += parseInt( $(this).attr('rel') ); 
});
```

But first, you need to attach a change event that triggers the calculations.

**NOTE:** I would suggest the use of `data-*` attributes instead like the sample below shows.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
  var modules = 0;
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    modules += parseInt($(this).data('rel'));
  });
  console.log(modules);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-rel="600">
<input type="checkbox" data-rel="1200">
```

Comment: You are my hero, the answer seems so simple, but It kept me busy for hours. Thank you. It's indeed working now.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently concatenating strings - turn them into numbers first:

```js
var modules = 0;
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
  modules += parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
});
console.log(modules);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" rel="600" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" rel="1200" checked="checked">
```